# Creating AsDoc I keep getting "Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: "

Tags: actionscript-3, asdoc

I'm trying to create AsDoc with Flash Develop tool :/.  It keeps giving me this error.

```
col: 41 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: antenaCoupler.
    public function AntennaKeyPad(v:antenaCoupler, m:AntennaCouplerModel, c:AntennaCouplerController)
```

It seems to be pointing at `v:antenaCoupler`.  I know that's spelled wrong but that's what the symbol is in the swc.  The application compiles fine to a swf.  I've been looking around but haven't found anything satisfying yet.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your settings to include the SWC location.

> -library-path C:\somefolder\myprojectlibs

Answer (score 0):

ASDocs will error out on anything that it does not understand. I have no idea what an antenaCoupler is, but try this instead

```
public function AntennaKeyPad(v:*, m:AntennaCouplerModel, c:AntennaCouplerController)
```

Comment: Antenna Coupler is an object in a swc. Your idea would here would work but it takes away from important restrictions.

Comment: I've grappled with ASDocs for a number of projects and it can be very difficult to get it to work if there is anything in the entire codebase the compiler doesn't like. If you can get it to work with the *, change it, publish the ASDocs, change it back, and consider yourself lucky that you can move on from this fiendish challenge.

Comment: The problem is that there are a ton more instances where I'm data typing with the same objects.  It would be a mess.